# Storing custom class object in Sqlite3 database failed

Tags: ios, objective-c, mailcore2

I want to store a custom class `MCOIMAPSession` object into sqlite3 database. I read about `NSKeyedArchiver` and trying to use that like below.

```
- (void) updateImapSessionForAccount :(NSString *) emailAddress :(MCOIMAPSession *)imapSession {

    const char *dbpath = [databasePath UTF8String];

    //SQLIte Statement
    NSString *selettablequery = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"select * from MailBoxInfoDBTable"];

    if (sqlite3_open(dbpath, &database) == SQLITE_OK)
    {

        //if(sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, [selettablequery UTF8String], -1, &statement, NULL) == SQLITE_OK)
        if (sqlite3_prepare(database, [selettablequery UTF8String], -1, &statement, NULL) ==SQLITE_OK)
        {
            // Take an array to store all string.
            //NSMutableArray *allRows = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

            while(sqlite3_step(statement) == SQLITE_ROW)
            {
                char *emailfield = (char *) sqlite3_column_text(statement,0);
                NSString *emailStr = [[NSString alloc] initWithUTF8String: emailfield];
                NSLog(@"updateMailMessagesPerAccount: %@", emailStr);

                if([emailStr isEqualToString:emailAddress])
                {
                    sqlite3_reset(statement);

                    NSData *messagesData = [NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:imapSession];
                    NSString* stringFromData = [messagesData base64EncodedStringWithOptions:0];                        

                    NSString *sqlStr = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"update MailBoxInfoDBTable set imapsession='%@' where emailid='%@'", stringFromData, emailAddress];

                    const char *updateStatement = [sqlStr UTF8String];

                    if (sqlite3_prepare(database, updateStatement, -1, &statement, NULL) == SQLITE_OK)
                    {
                        if(SQLITE_DONE != sqlite3_step(statement))
                            NSLog(@"Error while updating. %s", sqlite3_errmsg(database));

                        sqlite3_finalize(statement);
                        sqlite3_close(database);

                        return;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        NSLog(@"Error in statement: %s", sqlite3_errmsg(database));
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        sqlite3_finalize(statement);
        sqlite3_close(database);
    }

}

- (MCOIMAPSession *) retrieveImapSessionForAccount :(NSString *) emailAddress {

    MCOIMAPSession *imapsessionObj = nil;

    const char *dbpath = [databasePath UTF8String];

    //SQLIte Statement
    NSString *selettablequery = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"select * from MailBoxInfoDBTable"];

    if (sqlite3_open(dbpath, &database) == SQLITE_OK)
    {
        //if(sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, [selettablequery UTF8String], -1, &statement, NULL) == SQLITE_OK)
        if (sqlite3_prepare(database, [selettablequery UTF8String], -1, &statement, NULL) ==SQLITE_OK)
        {
            // Take an array to store all string.
            //NSMutableArray *allRows = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

            while(sqlite3_step(statement) == SQLITE_ROW)
            {
                char *emailfield = (char *) sqlite3_column_text(statement, 0);
                NSString *emailStr = [[NSString alloc] initWithUTF8String: emailfield];
                NSLog(@"retrieveImapSessionForAccount: Email: %@", emailStr);

                if([emailStr isEqualToString:emailAddress])
                {
                    //const void *bytes = sqlite3_column_blob(statement, 3);
                    char *emailstring = (char *) sqlite3_column_text(statement, 3);
                    if (emailstring) {
                        NSString *messageStr = [[NSString alloc] initWithUTF8String: emailstring];
                        NSData *data = [[NSData alloc] initWithBase64EncodedString:messageStr options:NSDataBase64DecodingIgnoreUnknownCharacters];
                        imapsessionObj = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:data];
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        sqlite3_finalize(statement);
        sqlite3_close(database);
    }

    return imapsessionObj;
}
```

I got crash `encodeWithCoder unrecognized selector sent to instance` when doing `NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:imapSession`

Then, I added the below methods in the 3rd party class `MCOIMAPSession.mm` file

```
- (void)encodeWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aCoder{
    [aCoder encodeObject:self forKey:@"PROPERTY_KEY"];
}

-(id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder{
    if(self = [super init]){
        self = [aDecoder decodeObjectForKey:@"PROPERTY_KEY"];
    }
    return self;
}
```

UPDATED: I tried the below as well.

```
  @interface MCOIMAPSession : NSObject
    ....
  @end
  @interface NSObject (NSCoding)
     -(id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder*)decoder;
     -(void)encodeWithCoder:(NSCoder*)encoder;
  @end
  #endif

@implementation MCOIMAPSession
-(id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)decoder {
    if ((self=[super initWithCoder:decoder])) {
    }
    return self;
}
@end
@implementation NSObject (NSCoding)
-(id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder*)decoder {
    return [self init];
}
-(void)encodeWithCoder:(NSCoder*)encoder {}
@end
```

HERE IS THE FILE OF MCOIMAPSESSION [MCOIMAPSESSION link](https://github.com/MailCore/mailcore2/blob/master/src/objc/imap/MCOIMAPSession.mm) .. Please let me know how can i add property now?

But, I see still the same crash. Could someone correct me what i'm doing wrong here when storing custom class `MCOIMAPSession` object in sqlite database?

Answer (score 2):

Your implementation of the `NSCoding` methods is incorrect. You don't encode/decode `self`, you encode/decode each property/ivar of `self`. Something like:

```
- (void)encodeWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aCoder{
    // Replace the following with the class's actual properties
    [aCoder encodeObject:self.propertyA forKey:@"propertyA"];
    [aCoder encodeObject:self.propertyB forKey:@"propertyB"];
    [aCoder encodeObject:self.propertyC forKey:@"propertyC"];
}

-(id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder{
    if(self = [super init]){
        // Replace the following with the class's actual properties
        _propertyA = [aDecoder decodeObjectForKey:@"propertyA"];
        _propertyB = [aDecoder decodeObjectForKey:@"propertyB"];
        _propertyC = [aDecoder decodeObjectForKey:@"propertyC"];
    }
    return self;
}
```

BTW - your question has nothing at all to do with SQLite. Your question should be narrowed down just to the problem with the encoding/decoding.

Comment: Quite right. Plus, this also assumes that this class is `NSObject` subclass (which this one happens to), otherwise you'd have to call the `super` methods, too, and make sure the super class conformed, too. Also, all of the properties of this class that are to be encoded must also conform to `NSCoding` (which they don't). This may take more work than the OP thinks.

Comment: I don't have any property here, I already mentioned I am storing in Sqlite DB not in NSUserDefaults. When we store NSUserDefaults only we need property of key and value pair.

Comment: @user1953977 - No, rmaddy is correct, that when making a class support archives (which you're attempting to do with `NSKeyedArchiver` prior to inserting into your database), you have to identify all of the individual properties that must be encoded. See [Encoding and Decoding Objects](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Archiving/Articles/codingobjects.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000948-BCIHBJDE) in the _Archives and Serializations Programming Guide._

Comment: Here is MCOIMAPSession file link  https://github.com/MailCore/mailcore2/blob/master/src/objc/imap/MCOIMAPSession.mm …. Please let me know how can i add property now?

Comment: @user1953977 - if you want to archive this, it's not a question of "how can I add property" but rather "I have to write encode and decode methods that go through all of the existing properties of this class." Frankly, I don't think that's a class that can be easily archived, or at least probably not worth the effort. Certainly queued tasks and operations will be lost. I'd be inclined to step back and ask "what do I need to save in order to recreate this in the future" and then save that information myself (with special care to be taken with the security concerns regarding storing a password).

Answer (score 0):

You cannot call `encodeWithCoder` with object `self`. You have to encode (and decode) **each relevant property** of the class `MCOIMAPSession`.

**Edit:**

For the `MCOIMAPSession` the NSCoding methods should look like

```
- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)decoder
{
  self = [super initWithCoder:decoder]
  if (self) {

    self.hostname = [decoder decodeObjectForKey:@"hostname"];
    self.port = [decoder decodeIntegerForKey:@"port"];
    self.username = [decoder decodeObjectForKey:@"username"];
    self.password = [decoder decodeObjectForKey:@"password"];
    // etc
  }
  return self;
}

-(void)encodeWithCoder:(NSCoder*)encoder
{
  [aCoder encodeObject:self.hostname forKey:@"hostname"];
  [aCoder encodeInteger:self.port forKey:@"port"];
  [aCoder encodeObject:self.username forKey:@"username"];
  [aCoder encodeObject:self.password forKey:@"password"];
  // etc
}
```

Add all properties you need. And consider that properties representing instances of other custom classes must be also NSCoding compliant.

Comment: I am not going to store in NSUserDefaults, so I don't have property to set there. I am trying to store MCOIMAPSession in Sqlite DB. How can i use encodeWithCoder in this case?

Comment: NSUserDefaults and Sqlite are quite similar. They both accept only data of specific types. Custom classes like `MCOIMAPSession` have to be encoded to binary data. That's what `NSKeyedArchiver` does. The `encodeWithCoder` method is used to encode properties like `host`, `port` `username`. The complementary method  `initWithCoder` is a kind of `initWithArguments` and creates a new `MCOIMAPSession` object assigning the values to the appropriate properties. If `MCOIMAPSession` does not conform to the NSCoding protocol you have to add a category providing the NSCoding methods

Comment: I can't use NSUserDefaults, since multiple MCOIMAPSession objects are being created dynamically in my app. NSUserDefaults key is static.

Comment: I understand that,  but you can't store pure MCOIMAPSession objects in Sqlite, you have to encode it to binary data (NSData) by implementing the NSCoding protocol

Comment: Here is MCOIMAPSession file link https://github.com/MailCore/mailcore2/blob/master/src/objc/imap/MCOIMAPSession.mm.  Please let me know how can i add property now?

Comment: I know the class. Once again, you have to encode/decode all properties you need for your purpose by adding appropriate lines  `self.<property> = [decoder decodeObjectForKey:@"<property>"];` and `[aCoder encodeObject:self.<property> forKey:@"<property>"];` I see no property `now`